# Get value from json in array of jsons in ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have the following JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "name":"x",
        "value":"y"
    },
    {
        "name":"y",
        "value":"z"
    },
    {
        "name":"w",
        "value":"q"
    }
]
```

how do i get the value from w?
i tried something like:

```
puts json['w']
```

but didnt work

Comment: There is no JSON objects in Ruby. You either have a string or an Array of Hashes. In the second case try `json.find { |h| h['name'] == 'w' }['value']`

Comment: Similar to @pavels comment but with protection against nulls `json.find { |nv_pair| nv_pair[:name] == 'w' }&.[](:value)` - ie no name/value pair for the given name

Comment: *"but didnt work"*, what is the error/result you're getting?

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". We have no idea what you tried. `puts json['w']` doesn't tell us enough.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a JSON string like this:

```
json = '[
    {
        "name":"x",
        "value":"y"
    },
    {
        "name":"y",
        "value":"z"
    },
    {
        "name":"w",
        "value":"q"
    }
]'
```

If it's just `name` and `value` and there are no duplicate names, you can parse it to a hash and simplify the hash like so:

```
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse(json)
json_hashed = json.map(&:values).to_h
#=> {"x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "w"=>"q"}
```

So you can call:

```
json_hashed['w'] #=> "q"
```

Comment: You shorten this by using [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-to_h) with a block `json.to_h(&:values)`, which is available since Ruby 2.6.0. I'd also recommend using [Here Documents](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) for multiline strings. `json = <<~JSON` followed by the string contents and closed with `JSON`.